# Passing any parameters in htaccess url rewriting (mod_rewrite in Apache)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want an URL like this:
`ht_tp://mysite.com/app/paramName1/value1/paramName2/value2/...`

To be translated to something like:
`ht_tp://mysite.com/app.php?paramName1=value1&paramName2=value2&...`

Can it be achieved with a single rule in .htaccess?

Notice that the number os parameters and the name of the 'app' will change constantly and I don't want to add a new rule/entry to every possibility.

Any ideas? Do I need to use a script to intercept the request (the app name and the rest of the URL and then split them into names and values) and then perform a redirection to the correct app?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is what I got so far:

```
RewriteRule ([^/]*)/(.*)?$ /translator.php?app=$1&params=$2 [NC,L]
```

It will split the URL and give me 2 parameters: 1st the app name (file name or whatever) and 2nd the list of paremeters separated by /

translator can, for example, include/import the content of that app and then parse the parameters list and make variables out of them (in a FOR loop)

Or I can try to call the app automatically

```
RewriteRule ([^/]*)/(.*)?$ /$1.php?params=$2 [NC,L]
```

or

```
RewriteRule ([^/]*)/(.*)?$ /$1/?params=$2 [NC,L]
```

Other suggestions will be appreciated!